# Entering person's full name with caps on the first letters in WP 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I want to make a text input like the one you have for adding a new contact's name.

When the empty input gets focus, the keyboard is on caps for the first letter and after you hit space, it switches the to caps again for the first letter.

I tried the `InoutScope` types, but only `Chat` started off with caps. How does the contacts app do it?

Edit:
It's an RT 8.1 phone app, not a Silverlight 8.1 phone app.

Comment: Why was this voted down?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [TextBox.InputScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.inputscope.aspx) property, by using the "[PersonalFullName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputscopenamevalue(v=vs.95).aspx)" value.

There are many other options available.

Comment: That scope is not available on RT kind, only Silverlight. Forgot to mention that in the initial post, thought there was a different tag for SL apps.